# tkinter disable right click on a pop-up menu

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, popup, right-click

I have a pop-up menu that comes up when I right click on a widget in tkinter

```
def popup(event):
    self.popup_menu.tk_popup(event,x, event.y, 0)

popup_menu = tk.Menu(widget, tearoff=False)
popup_menu.add_command(label='whatever', command=lambda: print('whatever'))
...
bind('<Button-3>', popup)
```

It pops up fine, but a command runs even when it is right clicked. I would like to make the command run only when it is left clicked, to prevent weird behavior when releasing the right button.

I've looked through the options [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#Tkinter.Menu.add-method), and there's not too much information elsewhere about pop-up menues. If anyone knows how to disable right-click or a work around pop-up where I can control things like that.

**EDIT:** my current work around is binding the popup to the release of the right button, so the release can't trigger an event. `bind('<ButtonRelease-3>', popup)'`

Comment: You can try calling `unbind("<Button 3>")` in the `popup` method or create a flag so you ignore the second popup call.

Comment: The problem isn't another popup showing up, its the release of the right button pressing one of the menu buttons